# How to communicate scope data through multiple angular app?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-app

I have separate login ng-app and index page ng-app
So how would I get LoginData scope into index ng-app?

Answer (score 0):

you create a service and inject it as dependancy in your two controllers to share data between them. 
a service is a singleton.

many source on google, search "angularjs share data between controllers" : 
a good solution here
[Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers)

Comment: i am not asking about between two controller

Comment: sorry. misunderstand your need. 
maybe with cookies ?

Comment: Actually i bought an angular admin panel template..which works fine on index.html page..but i need to merge login module too...So i created Login app and merge with their app.. Now i want to pass login rootScope data into index app..and also need separate 'username' entity too..how can i approach too this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using localStorage (HTML5) through angularJS